# dimension of orthogonal complement of complete orthonormal sets

Tags: functional-analysis, orthogonality, eigenfunctions

I'm thinking about the following problem and get stuck.

I consider a complete orthonormal set $\{\psi_i\}^{\infty}_{i=0}$ defined on $\mathbb{R}$, and the inner product is defined by $$(\psi_i,\psi_j)=\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}\psi_i(x)\psi_j(x)\,dx$$ In this sense, I consider a finite-dimensional space $E_k$ spanned by $\{\psi_i\}^{k-1}_{i=0}$, and assume that $\psi_k$ has $(k+1)$ zeros, and denote these $(k+1)$ zeros of $\psi_k$ by $\beta_1,\beta_2,\cdots,\beta_{k+1}$. Now I define a space $\Phi_{k+2}$ spanned by
$$
\begin{aligned}
    &\phi_1(x)=
    \begin{cases}
    \psi_k(x)\quad \text{for}\ x\in(-\infty,\beta_1),\\
    0\quad \text{otherwise}
    \end{cases}\\
    &\phi_2(x)=
    \begin{cases}
    \psi_k(x)\quad \text{for}\ x\in(\beta_1,\beta_2),\\
    0\quad \text{otherwise}
    \end{cases}\\
    &\cdots\\
    &\phi_{k+2}(x)=
    \begin{cases}
    \psi_k(x)\quad \text{for}\ x\in(\beta_{k+1},\infty),\\
    0\quad \text{otherwise}
    \end{cases}
\end{aligned}
$$
Obviously, $\{\phi_i\}^{k+2}_{i=1}$ is linearly independent, so it's a basis.
There is a claim that $\dim({E^\perp_k\,\cap\, \Phi_{k+2}})\geq2$. What I know is at least, $\phi_k\in{E^\perp_k\,\cap\, \Phi_{k+2}}$, but where is the other basis?
Appreciate for any help.

Comment: $\Phi_{k+2}$ is a $k+2$ dimensional space. $E_k$ is a $k$ dimensional space. Even if $E_k \subset \Phi_{k+2}$, there wouls still have to be two dimensions of  $\Phi_{k+2}$ perpendicular to $E_k$.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Awesome!